# How to refresh browser cache?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have been stuck for a while on this mistake and I just can't seem to find it. I get this error:

> ERROR: SyntaxError: Unexpected string in JSON at position 1

I am trying to do an AJAX-request to dashboard.php using this dashboard.js file:

```
$(".next").click(function(){
    console.log("next uitgevoerd");
    i++;
    huidige_pagina += 1;
    document.getElementById("pagina").innerHTML = huidige_pagina;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://goad-as-05/ramon/logic/dashboard.php',
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: { "pagina": i },
        success: function (resultaat) {
            alert(resultaat);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            alert('ERROR: ' + errorThrown); 
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the php-code:

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8", true);
if(isset($_POST["pagina"])){
$pageno = $_POST["pagina"];
echo $pageno;
} else {
echo "foutje";
}


 // $url will contain the API endpoint
 $url = "https://app.teamleader.eu/api/getContacts.php";

// $fields contains all the fields that will be POSTed
$fields = array(  
"api_group"=>(GROUP_KEY),
"api_secret"=>(SECRET_KEY),
"amount"=>2,
"pageno"=>$pageno
 );

  // Make the POST request using Curl
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);

 // Decode and display the output
 $api_output =  curl_exec($ch);
 echo curl_error($ch);
  //$json_output = json_decode($api_output);


  echo json_encode($api_output);
  header('application/json');

  // Clean up
  curl_close($ch);

  ?>
```

Here is my html:

```
  <div class="pagina">
       <p id="pagina">1</p>
  </div>
```

I am sure it is not my URL, as both files are in the same folder.

Do I have to use `JSON.stringify("pagina":i)` first and use that?

Any help is appreciated, it probably is the smallest mistake I just can't seem to find.

SOLUTION FOUND:
Refresh my javascript with ctrl+F5 when loading it, completely forgot about cache.... thanks everyone for trying to help!

Ramon

Comment: i have a var i = 0; outside this function

Comment: is there relevance to the php tag? there's no code to support it

Comment: The error is because the data being returned is not valid JSON. You will need to investigate why that is happening on the server.

Comment: I removed the tag.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the response you're getting from the server (if you visit the URL directly for example)

Comment: We need to see your PHP code, as there's nothing inherently wrong with the JS

Comment: so now it is potentially a php-related question, seeing this after revisiting the question. If so, "you" should add the php tag back in (it's important that you do) and add that code.

Comment: By the way you don't need to send the `contentType` that's already the default value sent by jQuery

Comment: `getElementById` - the HTML could also be of help.

Comment: "Undefined variable: pagina in dashboard.php"  You're _absolutely sure_ that that's the exact error you're getting?

Comment: Just as a test, replace `data: { "pagina": i },` with `data: { "pagina": 1 },` and see what happens

Comment: doing pagination, usually requires/uses a GET method and not a POST method.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't notice this earlier.  `data: { "pagina": i }` should be `data: { pagina: i }`.  No quotes around the parameter name. Voting to close this as a typo.

Comment: It will solve your "Undefined variable" error. It will not solve your JSON error because you're not responding with valid JSON from your PHP file. Either respond with valid JSON (remove _all_ other `echo`s) or change your ajax call to not require a JSON response.

Comment: @PatrickQ i wish it would solve that error, but my server still says undefined variable error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP, you can not use the HEADER function after an output.

```
  echo json_encode($api_output);
  header('application/json'); // delete this line
```

the server ends up producing an error that makes the JSON string unusable.

**EDIT:**

```
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8", true);
if(isset($_POST["pagina"])){
$pageno = $_POST["pagina"];
echo $pageno; // ERROR
} else {
echo "foutje";
}
```

with the **echo $pageno;** line write the result sent by POST generating an error.

**EDIT 2:**

```
echo curl_error($ch);
```

This line also produces an unencoded output in JSON

**EDIT 3:**
I'm happy that you've been able to find the solution to your problem and to prevent it from happening again I suggest you edit the JS file address so:

```
echo 'dashboard.js?'.time(); // disable browser cache
```

Comment: I modified my answer.

Comment: The error would be this: Notice: Undefined index: pagina in C:\wamp64\www\ramon\logic\dashboard.php on line 4

Comment: Removed it, but it didn't matter as the problem is earlier somewhere

Comment: I mean my php doesn't receive anything from JS so the mistake should be in JS right?

Comment: in your current question, lines 3,4,5 appear to be no errors. can you update the question?

Comment: A small question: what is the output of the dashboard.php file?

Comment: This error: Undefined index: pagina in C:\wamp64\www\ramon\logic\dashboard.php on line 4 is from dashboard.php, because he can't see the variable sent from javascript

Comment: Are you sure? the isset($_POST["pagina"]) variable being contained within the ISSET function should not produce such errors. If you want, you can silence the function using @ as a prefix. (@isset($_POST["pagina"] ))

Alternatively, you can also specify a default value for that variable.

Comment: thank you for trying to help me, look at my solution given

Comment: I modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the the browser cache, i forgot to use ctrl + f5 to reload the cache and reload my javascript that way, thanks for the help everyone!